# Указатели, не понимаю почему не компилируется

Tags: c, указатели

```
        *count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++)
        {
            if (*pa < 0)
            {
                *count2++;
                printf("count2 %d %d<- ", *count2, i);
            }
            else 
            {
                *count++;
                printf("count %d %d <- ", *count,i);
            }
            pa++;
        }
        if ((*count == 0) || (*count2 == 0))
            key = 1;
```

компилятор говорит, что count2 и count не используются, но я использую его в предпоследней строчке, в чем проблема? язык С

Comment: язык-то какой?..

Comment: @PavelMayorov русский

Comment: с ...............

Comment: "Огласите весь список, пжлста..." (с)  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3):

У оператора постфиксного `++` большой приоритет, больше чем у взятия значения `*` . Ваша команда `*count2++;` вычисляется так : `*(count2++);`

Сначала указателю даётся задача инкрементироваться (поменяеть адрес на другое), а затем берётся значение этого указателя (текущее). Вы значение игнорируете, по-этому выдаётся предупреждение. Только потом сам указатель ещё и меняется.

Скорее всего вам нужно правильно скобки поставить : `(*count2)++;`.